# How can I iterate over a Decoder?

Tags: go

I come from a Python background and so have a tendency to think in terms of iterators.  It seems to me that the `range` keyword in Go intends for us to think in a nearly identical way, so I would like to do somthing semantically equivalent to this Python code in Go:

```
for obj in json_decoder:
    # business logic
```

Here is the motivating case in Go; consider the following function:

```
func (c *GorpController) Create(dec *json.Decoder) {
    // business logic
}
```

I would like to be able to implement it as:

```
for someValue := range dec {
    // business logic
}
```

Is there some sort of way to use `range` with a `Decoder` interface?  A function that wraps it in a different interface would be ideal, and an idiomatic pattern would be acceptable.

Thank you!

Comment: I think the paradigm you want to embody would be better served by unmarshalling into a `map[string]interface{}` and then iterating it's keys and values. Should you need the decoder (perhaps the incoming data is to large to have in memory at once) check out the docs, https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder there are methods to return the next item in the stream, check for it ect. The example for the `Decode` method should serve well since it's essentially what you're trying to do.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal, thanks for this helpful reply. Perhapse I'm not quite understanding the idea of `Decoder.Buffered`.  I ask because it's the only thing that seems to mention memory:  is the idea that all the data *aren't* read at once, but gradually paged into a memory buffer?

Comment: I haven't used that class for a bit but yes, I believe data is buffered as needed so if you're dealing with a large stream of data it is the common approach. If you're dealing with a data set that can easily be held in memory, more often you'll unmarshal into an object and deal with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can only use `range` with an "array, slice, string, or map, or reading from a channel" (see [effective go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#for))

to iterate over structs as they get decoded, the documentation recommends doing:

```
dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(jsonStream))
for {
    var m Message
    if err := dec.Decode(&m); err == io.EOF {
        break
    } else if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", m.Name, m.Text)
}
```

(taken directly from the [official doc example](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder))

Answer (score 1):

A `json.Decoder` is a struct, and in Go, you can only iterate (use `range`) over strings, slices/arrays, maps and channels (https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements).

You can, however, loop over all JSON-encoded values in an `io.Reader`:

```
func main() {
    s := `"a string"
72
["an", "array"]
{"an": "object"}
`
    dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(s))
    for {
        var v interface{}
        if err := dec.Decode(&v); err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        log.Print(v)
    }
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/flqXlcx_6B

EDIT: although `More` does seem to work for values as in this example, it is not its intended usage (based on the godoc), so checking for err == io.EOF would be better. Updated the code snippet.

Comment: Just to be sure... is this the correct way of handling reads that expect lots of data?  Perhaps my problem is better solved by a buffer of some sort?

Comment: Will you be handling a bunch of distinct JSON values from a Reader, or just one big JSON object, or something else? Decoder does use a buffer, but it will get as big as the biggest value you read. If a single value can potentially be very big and you don't want to load it all in memory, you can use the `Decoder.Token` approach (https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Token)

Comment: Then that would be the correct way, unless you expect a single value can get unreasonably large, in which case you could use the Token approach which requires more work on your part (and can still cause memory issues if, say, a single JSON string value is very large). If you know the JSON values will be reasonable, the loop with Decoder.Decode is fine.